# How can I return a different array?

Tags: javascript

I need to return an array consisting of the largest number from each provided sub-array. So, I've written the following code and it works but I have:
`[[25],[48],[21],[-3]]` instead of `[25,48,21,-3]`. Can I change something to get the right answer?

```js
function largestOfFour(arr) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i].sort(function(a,b) {
            return b - a;
        }).map(function() {
            return arr[i].splice(1);
        })
    }
    return arr;
}

var result = largestOfFour([[17, 23, 25, 12], [25, 7, 34, 48], [4, -10, 18, 21], [-72, -3, -17, -10]]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: One way is that you can [flatten](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop and sort, then return the first element of each sub-array with `map`;

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
   for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      arr[i].sort(function(a,b) {
         return b - a;
      });
   }
   return arr.map(array => array[0]);
}
```

Better still, do it in one.

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
    return arr.map(array => array.sort((a,b) => b - a)[0]);
}
```

Comment: Better still, use `Math.max` instead of `sort`.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `map` with spread syntax `...` to return 1D array as pointed out by **@str** .

```js
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  return arr.map(a => Math.max(...a))
}

const arr = [[17, 23, 25, 12], [25, 7, 34, 48], [4, -10, 18, 21], [-72, -3, -17, -10]]
const result = largestOfFour(arr);
console.log(result)
```

You could also use `reduce`

```js
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((r, a) => r.concat(Math.max(...a)), [])
}

const arr = [[17, 23, 25, 12], [25, 7, 34, 48], [4, -10, 18, 21], [-72, -3, -17, -10]]
const result = largestOfFour(arr);
console.log(result)
```

Comment: `concat` is not even needed, `arr.map(a => Math.max(...a))` is enough.

Comment: `return arr.map(function(a) { return Math.max.apply(Math, a); });` If you need to support IE

Answer (score 0):

get the first character of each array using `[0]` index like this

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

    arr[i].sort(function(a,b) {
      return b - a;

    }).map(function() {
       // HERE
       return arr[i].splice(1)[0];

    })

  }
  return arr;
}

largestOfFour([[17, 23, 25, 12], [25, 7, 34, 48], [4, -10, 18, 21], [-72, -3, -17, -10]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could map the first element of the descending sorted elements.

```js
function largestOfFour(array) {
    return array.map(a => a.sort((a, b) => b - a)[0]);
}

console.log(largestOfFour([[17, 23, 25, 12], [25, 7, 34, 48], [4, -10, 18, 21], [-72, -3, -17, -10]]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` which will return a new array and then use `Math.max` to get the maximum value form the array

```js
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  return arr.map(item => {
    return [Math.max.apply(null, item)]

  })
}

console.log(largestOfFour([
  [17, 23, 25, 12],
  [25, 7, 34, 48],
  [4, -10, 18, 21],
  [-72, -3, -17, -10]
]));
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use flat function for it

```
var arr1 = [1, 2, [3, 4]];
    arr1.flat(); 
    // [1, 2, 3, 4]

    var arr2 = [1, 2, [3, 4, [5, 6]]];
    arr2.flat();
    // [1, 2, 3, 4, [5, 6]]

    var arr3 = [1, 2, [3, 4, [5, 6]]];
    arr3.flat(2);
    // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: It's always better to mention the source of our answers:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat#Flattening_nested_arrays

Comment: Note that this is not supported in IE or Edge